# QZ tray save data to pdf instead of printing it

Tags: javascript, qz-tray

Can we do something like saving pdf from the raw code of QZ tray?
Instead of printing can we save result data to pdf? like passing raw code of barcode or labels and saving the resultant output to pdf.

Comment: I don't have a printer nither I don't need any but I have qz raw commands which I want to store in pdf form. i don't want to print any pdf

Comment: thank you kj i think i need to ask this on their support. but thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, very few [raw](https://qz.io/wiki/raw) printer emulators exist.  For those that do, QZ has compiled a list of known working emulators: https://qz.io/wiki/printer-emulators

Although most do not specifically support outputting PDF, some are capable of visualizing the receipt or label output to the screen.

For labels and barcodes specifically, if ZPL is a viable option, [Labelary](http://labelary.com/viewer.html) is the single source I've found, with a [Desktop app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zpl-printer/phoidlklenidapnijkabnfdgmadlcmjo) available as well.